# Power BI : Find average per ID

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I'm new to PowerBI and I have this table:

[image]

So a bit of explanation:

- ID : unique ID which represent a task's execution
- DT_START : beginning of the execution
- DT_END : end of the execution
- ID_OBJECT : ID of the related task / plan
- Duration : number of seconds between DT_START abd DT_END

I want to add a new column or measure not sure what's best in this case that contains the average of duration per ID_OBJECT. So for example with the ID_OBJECT that appears in the picture I should have a column with this value (rounded : 277):

[image]

I need this output :

[image]

I tried a few solutions like creating a calculated column with :

```
AverageDuration = AVERAGEX(DISTINCT(SELECTCOLUMNS('EXECUTIONS', "ID_OBJ", [ID_OBJECT])), [Duration])
```

Or :

```
var id_obj = 'EXECUTIONS'[ID_OBJECT]

Return
AVERGEX(
    FILTER(ALL('EXECUTIONS'), 'EXECUTIONS'[ID_OBJECT] = id_obj), 'EXECUTIONS'[Duration]
)
```

But I don't have the output I need

[image]

So what is the best way to achieve this.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to do with the average duration? If you need to use it to group records, you'd create a calculated column. If you wanted to just calculate a MIN/MAX/AVG etc, you'd create a measure.
you can use a calculated column to bin the values. Duration = DATEDIFF('WorkTime'[EndTime],'WorkTime'[StartTime],MINUTE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this measure

```
AverageDuration = CALCULATE(AVERAGE('EXECUTIONS'[Duration]), ALLEXCEPT('EXECUTIONS', 'EXECUTIONS'[ID_OBJECT]) )
```